# Create table with stored procedure in Teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

I want to create a stored procedure where I can pass in variable to the WHERE clause below.

```
DROP TABLE fan0ia_mstr.Store_List;

CREATE TABLE fan0ia_mstr.Store_List AS(

SELECT
a11.ANA_Code,
a11.Premise_Name_Full,
a11.Store_Code,
a11.Estates_Segment,
a12.Post_Code
FROM Store_Dimension_Hierarchy a11
JOIN Location a12
ON a11.ANA_Code = a12.ANA_Code
WHERE a11.Area_Desc = 'VARIABLE' ) WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX (ANA_Code)
```

The VARIABLE will be a character string.  I don't need to display the results, I just want the table to be created.

Also how do I trap any errors e.g. if the table doesn't exist for some reason I still want it to be created

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have variable database/table/column names you simply need to wrap your existing code (slightly modified) into a Stored Procedure:

```
replace procedure myproc(IN variable varchar(100))
begin

   BEGIN
      -- simply try dropping the table and ignore the "table doesn't exist error"
      DECLARE exit HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
      BEGIN  -- 3807 = table doesn't exist
         IF SQLCODE <> 3807 THEN RESIGNAL; END IF;
      END;

      DROP TABLE fan0ia_mstr.Store_List;
   END;


   CREATE TABLE fan0ia_mstr.Store_List AS(

   SELECT
   a11.ANA_Code,
   a11.Premise_Name_Full,
   a11.Store_Code,
   a11.Estates_Segment,
   a12.Post_Code
   FROM Store_Dimension_Hierarchy a11
   JOIN Location a12
   ON a11.ANA_Code = a12.ANA_Code
   WHERE a11.Area_Desc = :variable ) WITH DATA
   PRIMARY INDEX (ANA_Code);

end;
```

Of course a DELETE/INSERT or a Temporary table might be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks!  If I want to create a temp table do I just need to add the word 'volatile' between the CREATE and TABLE?

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek: ... and add `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` after the PI.

Comment: Excellent thanks for the quick reply, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Edited... second option needs a execute immediate too...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1(
    V_AREA_DESC IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE fan0ia_mstr.Store_List';
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
   NULL;
  END;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE fan0ia_mstr.Store_List AS
    (SELECT a11.ANA_Code,
        a11.Premise_Name_Full,
        a11.Store_Code,
        a11.Estates_Segment,
        a12.Post_Code
      FROM Store_Dimension_Hierarchy a11
      JOIN Location a12
      ON a11.ANA_Code     = a12.ANA_Code
      WHERE a11.Area_Desc =  ''' || v_area_desc || '''
    ) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (ANA_Code)';

END PROCEDURE1;
```

but you can avoid drop / create with truncate / insert

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1(
   V_AREA_DESC IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'truncate TABLE fan0ia_mstr.Store_List';

  insert into fan0ia_mstr.Store_List (SELECT a11.ANA_Code,
        a11.Premise_Name_Full,
        a11.Store_Code,
        a11.Estates_Segment,
        a12.Post_Code
      FROM Store_Dimension_Hierarchy a11
      JOIN Location a12
      ON a11.ANA_Code     = a12.ANA_Code
      WHERE a11.Area_Desc =  v_area_desc 
    );

  commit;

END PROCEDURE1;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I get the following error messages when I try and run either of the above:

`3707:  Syntax error, expected something like a 'METHOD' keyword between the 'CREATE' keyword and the 'OR' keyword. 
Output directed to Answerset window`

Comment: This is Oracle code, but Teradata's SP syntax is based on Standard SQL.